# Bitmap.Clone creates an image that is 4x Larger in output size than original

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, clone

So, I have an app that takes an original image, gets the new new cropped region, and then saves the cropped version of the image as a new file.  It works perfectly with one major drawback.  The new image is, on average, 4x larger than the original image.  In my test, I have a photograph that has a size on disk of ~4.5MB, and the cropped version (which is properly cropped and looks fine) is ~21MB on disk.  The code is as follows:

```
var originalImage = new Bitmap(imagePath);
var fWidth = originalImage.PhysicalDimension.Width;
var fHeight = originalImage.PhysicalDimension.Height;   

float calculatedWidth = GetCroppedWidth();
float calculatedHeight = GetCroppedHeight();

//Draw the image by centering the cropped region on the original
var heightOffset = (fHeight - calculatedHeight) / 2;
var widthOffset = (fWidth - calculatedWidth) / 2;
var sourceRectF = new RectangleF(widthOffset, heightOffset, calculatedWidth, calculatedHeight);
var croppedImage = originalImage.Clone(sourceRectF, originalImage.PixelFormat);

//Save the image
croppedImage.Save(croppedFileName);
```

Comment: What is the graphics format of the input file?

Comment: Sorry, I should've posted that it is a jpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the image you are loading is some other format than BMP (e.g. PNG or JPG).

Use another overload of [`Bitmap.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx) that specified an [`ImageFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx)

Comment: That was exactly it.  Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Bitmap.Save overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) that lets you choose the output format.
By default, it is Bmp i guess, which has no compression.

so, in your case use

```
croppedImage.Save(croppedFileName, originalImage.RawFormat);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I appreciate it.